# What kind of sander do I need to get the paint off this kind of fence?

Tags: fence, sanding

I have a fence with a tricky structure with regard to how to sand it. What kind of sander should I get to remove the paint from this fence?

[image]

Comment: Are you removing the boards or you are hoping to sand in place?

Comment: I am curious why you want to remove the paint.  Could you just wash the fence and then paint over what is there?

Comment: I was hoping to sand in place. Parts of the paint are in really bad shape; it can't just be painted over. Otherwise, good suggestion :)